# Движение объекта (HTML5 canvas)

Tags: canvas, javascript, html5, алгоритм

Привет всем, нужна реализация следующего: анимация по рандомным координатам ходит в произвольные стороны в рамках разрешения пользователя. Каков алгоритм сего действия?

Comment: По рандомным координатам, или по рандомным направлениям? Просто в первом случае, это уже не совсем анимация.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Генерируешь рандомный X
2. Проверяешь, не вылазит ли он за пределы экрана
3. Генерируешь рандомный Y
4. Проверяешь, не вылазит ли он за пределы экрана
5. Указываешь координаты твоему объекту
6. Делаешь [паузу](http://www.next-step.ru/blog/%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B5-javascript.htm)
7. Повторяешь 1-6 пункт